# Complete case analysis in (long) dataset with repeated measurements

Tags: r

I have a dataset with repeated measurements, which is in long format.

We are using complete case analysis. Our endpoint assesses the reduction of a variable from baseline to month 3 and from baseline to month 6 and between intervention and control group.

I need that for each ID, both data at baseline and at month 3 or at baseline and at month 6. However, as my data is in long format - and I’d prefer not to switch it to wide - if I just use e.g. drop_na() it can happen I just delete the row with missing data for one timepoint, although if that ID doesn’t have data for the other timepoint, it should be made missing as well.

In the example below, id 423 and id 143 should be removed, because they only have information at baseline.

Does anyone have any idea how to solve this?

Thanks a lot!

Dataframe structure:

```
a <- structure(list(id = c(778, 778, 101, 101, 101, 543, 543, 543, 
423, 315, 315, 315, 491, 491, 504, 504, 708, 708, 708, 714, 714, 
714, 408, 408, 418, 418, 279, 279, 279, 143), time = c(0, 6, 
0, 3, 6, 0, 3, 6, 0, 0, 3, 6, 0, 6, 0, 6, 0, 3, 6, 0, 3, 6, 0, 
3, 0, 6, 0, 3, 6, 0), group = c("control", "control", "intervention", 
"intervention", "intervention", "intervention", "intervention", 
"intervention", "intervention", "control", "control", "control", 
"control", "control", "intervention", "intervention", "control", 
"control", "control", "intervention", "intervention", "intervention", 
"control", "control", "control", "control", "control", "control", 
"control", "control"), var = c(46, 72, 90, 50, 73, 90, 96, 95, 
75, 50, 80, 66, 52, 70, 100, 84, 90, 96, 85, 88, 88, 92, 60, 
30, 95, 71, 86, 80, 91, 100)), row.names = c(NA, -30L), class = "data.frame")

> print(a)
```

Comment: if you need complete obs and you have 3 time points should all of the ids with 2 obs also be removed?

Comment: No. But actually, I need that ids have always info at baseline and not only at two follow-up time points. My example did not include this case though.

Comment: ok I update my answer to include your last point. The code should keep everyone who has a baseline and at least one follow-up time point.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

one way using `dplyr`. You can group by id and then count with the `n()` function and finally filter to where there is more than one observation.

```
library(dplyr)

                                                                                                                                                 
a2 <- a |> 
      group_by(id) |> 
      mutate(obs = n()) |> 
      filter(obs > 1)
```

or if you do not want to make another variable you can leave out the mutate statement.

```
a2 <- a |> 
      group_by(id) |> 
      filter(n() > 1)
```

if you need complete observation and they need all time points simply change the filter statement.

```
a2 <- a |> 
      group_by(id) |> 
      filter(n() == 3)
```

This should work for the longitudinal analysis. Below I am making sure they have a baseline and also more than one observation. So if they had only 3 and 6 months they would be dropped. I would need more data to test this though because that case is not in your data.

```
a2 <- a |> 
  group_by(id) |> 
  mutate(obs = n()) |> 
  filter(obs > 1 & any(time == 0))
```

Answer (score 1):

If I understood correctly basline is when `time = 0`. You can select the `id` that has an observation which has value at `time` other than 0.

```
library(dplyr)

a %>% group_by(id) %>% filter(any(time != 0)) %>% ungroup

#     id  time group          var
#   <dbl> <dbl> <chr>        <dbl>
# 1   778     0 control         46
# 2   778     6 control         72
# 3   101     0 intervention    90
# 4   101     3 intervention    50
# 5   101     6 intervention    73
# 6   543     0 intervention    90
# 7   543     3 intervention    96
# 8   543     6 intervention    95
# 9   315     0 control         50
#10   315     3 control         80
# … with 18 more rows
```

Here are corresponding base R and `data.table` options -

```
#Base R
subset(a, ave(time != 0, id, FUN = any))

#data.table
library(data.table)
setDT(a)[, .SD[any(time != 0)], id]
```

Answer (score 0):

We may use

```
library(dplyr)
a %>%
    group_by(id) %>%
    filter(!all(time == 0)) %>%
    ungroup
```